# Defining an object which is function in some variables and tensor in some other indices

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to define an object which function in some variable and tensor in other indices. 
My attempt at it was:

```
Clear[mat, k];
mat[k_] := {{0,0},{0,0}};
mat[k_][[1, 1]] := k + 1
mat[k_][[1, 2]] := k + 2
mat[k_][[2, 1]] := k + 3
mat[k_][[2, 2]] := k + 4
mat[1]
```

The ouput it gives is:

```
During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part    assignment is not a symbol. >>

Out[270]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Out[271]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Out[272]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
Out[273]= $Failed

Out[274]= {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Could someone please points me out as to what's going wrong here and what are the ways to get what i want?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome on Stackoverflow. Notice you can also post on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ where many experts would help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

`mat[k_]` is a pattern not a symbol. `mat[k_] := {{0,0},{0,0}}` defines a single variable function that returns the 2x2 array.  `mat[k_]` has `Head` `mat` and `Part` 1 `k_`.

I believe you want to define `mat` has follows in its own cell.

```
mat[k_] := {{k + 1, k + 2}, {k + 3, k + 4}}
```

Then in another cell

```
mat[1]
(* {{2, 3}, {4, 5}} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to define the way you suggest because in my origional code, which motivated me to write this problem, i need to define a matrix (not just 2*2) whose blocks are given as a function of some variable which is k here.

Comment: Have a look at `Table`.